# Send message content to a channel when it matches word

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am looking to send a message to my logging channel when a user types something important (for a game server) what I have now doesn't work and just spams messages for some reason. if you know how to fix this and make it work and not spam messages, that would be good. (no errors in console)

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
if (message.content.startsWith("####")) return; {}
const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get('783009285709496371');
logChannel.send(`User: <@${message.author.id}> | Message: ${message.content}`);
})
```

Comment: Do the #s mean the question is important?

Comment: the # is where the trigger word is (blanked out because its easier)

Comment: Ok then my answer is correct, you nees to either invert it, or put the action in the if clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the return condition. Right now you are sensing all messages that dont start with `#####`.
Put a `!` in front of the content check.